# Use a static value in class extends

Tags: java

I would like to use a method using a constant according to class she is called.
Sorry for this bad explanation, here is an example :

```
public class Mom{
   public void execute(parameters){
      // Some actions
       String nf = String.format(C_CARS)
   }
}

public class Son1 extends Mom{
   private static final String C_CARS=" myFormat " 
}


public class Son2 extends Mom{
   private static final String C_CARS=" myFormat2 " 
}

public static void main(String[] args){
   Son1 son1=new Son1();
   Son2 son2=new Son2();
   son1().execute(myparameters);
   son2().execute(myparameters);
}
```

I would like to do something like that, is there a way ? The problem here is C_CARS is unknown in Mom Class.

Comment: Mom class is the super class of Son1 and Son2 class. Therefore, the subclass variables are not accessible in the superclass.

Comment: Even if Java fields worked polymorphically, how would you expect this to work for `class Son3 extends Mom { /* no constant */ }`?

Comment: Overwrite the `execute` method in both yhe Son1 and Son2 class.

Comment: Even in real world we cant keep anything private from Mom, but In Java world, anything `private` to class stays private ;)

Comment: @SagarRohankar I love that explanation xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just not how inheritance works in Java.

You need a guarantee that all instances of `Mom` have a value. Do this via an instance method, e.g.

```
 public abstract class Mom{
   public void execute(parameters){
     String nf = String.format(getCCars());
   }
   protected abstract String getCCars();
 }
```

And then implement in the child classes:

```
class Son1 extends Mom {
  @Override protected String getCCars() {
    return "something";
  }
}
```

---

There is something up with your object oriented design.

Remember: every instance of a `Son1` class is also an instance of `Mom`. But in the real world, most sons aren't mothers.

`extends` is not the right thing to use here.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override a variable in this way. Use a method instead:

```
abstract public class Mom {
    abstract protected String cCars();

    public void execute(parameters){
       // Some actions
       String nf = String.format(cCars())
    }
}

public class Son1 extends Mom{
    private static final String C_CARS=" myFormat ";

    @Override
    protected String cCars() {
        return C_CARS;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could provide a default implementation in `Mom`, then there is no need to make the class and method abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `static`, it brings troubles.

```
public class Mom {
    private final String cCars;
    protected Mom(String cCars) {
        this.cCars = cCars;
    }
    public void execute(parameters){
        // Some actions
        String nf = String.format(cCars)
    }
}

public class Son1 extends Mom {
    public Son1() {
        super(" myFormat ");
    }
}


public class Son2 extends Mom {
    public Son2() {
        super(" myFormat2 ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't work because a superclass cannot access the members of it's subclass. Also, you can't override a variable like you can override methods. Try it with the following code instead:

```
public static abstract class Mom {
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println(getCCars());
    }

    abstract String getCCars();
}

public static class Son1 extends Mom {

    @Override
    String getCCars() {
        return " myFormat ";
    }
}

public static class Son2 extends Mom {

    @Override
    String getCCars() {
        return " myFormat2 ";
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Son1 son1 = new Son1();
    Son2 son2 = new Son2();
    son1.execute();
    son2.execute();
}
```

This is the way you would to it in java.

I've tested the code above. It does compile and it produces the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

A field marked `static` belongs to the class rather than an instance. Also, `C_CARS` in `Son1` is not related in any way to `C_CARS` in `Son2`.

- A way to achieve such thing is this:

  ```
  class Mom {
      public abstract String getCCars();
  }
  ```

  Then each ascendant of `Mom` must override the `getCCars()` method.
- You could also accept a string `cCars` in the constructor of `Mom`. Each ascendant then must call the super constructor defined in `Mom`:

  ```
  class Mom {

      final String cCars;

      Mom(String cCars) {
          this.cCars = cCars;
      }

      void execute(String parameters) {
          System.out.println(this.cCars);
      }
  }

  class Son1 {

      Son1() {
          super("MyFormat"); // We have to call the super constructor
      }
  }
  ```